# Dynamic test cases in Nunit3

Tags: automated-tests, nunit

I have integer values as test cases(ids of different users), and I don't want to hardcode them, I have a method that gets users from API. It is said [in specs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Specifications), that dynamic test cases spec is not implemented yet. Is it possible to load test cases before test is executed?

Comment: It would be great, if you can share more details with trial code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have used the term "dynamic test cases" to mean that the tests are not created before the run but during it. Specifically, the test cases can change **while the test is running**.

It doesn't sound like this is what you need. If I understand correctly, you want to get the user ids programmatically at the time the tests are created. You can easily do this using the `TestCaseSourceAttribute` on a method that uses your API to get the user id.